# "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subside = 0x0)

Tags: swift, xcode, null, option-type

sorry Im new to stack overflow so I may be posting this in the wrong format..

Im trying to set up my login, so a user enters their username and password into two text fields. If they had already made an account, they press the "login" button and continue. If their making a new account, they press the "Register" button and it directs them to a new view controller. In this controller, I want to take the data they entered into the previous text fields, and fill out the new username and password text fields in the registration page.

Ive tried to follow youtube videos on how to do this, but I keep getting this stupid error and I don't know how to get around it.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Silver
//
//  Created by Lakeside Software on 3/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 KenSchumacher. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var returningEmail: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var returningPassword: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func LoginFunction(_ sender: Any) {

    func login() {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: returningEmail.text!, password: returningPassword.text!, completion: {
            user, error in

            if error != nil{
                //Password is not right
                print("Password is incorrect")
            }
            else {
                //password is correct
                print("Welcome in")
            }
        })
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var UsernameForRegistrationText: UITextField!


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var DestViewController = segue.destination as! viewTwo


   if UsernameForRegistrationText == nil
   {
    DestViewController.viewTwo.text = "0"
    }
   else {
    //DestViewController.testLabel.text =      UsernameForRegistrationText.text!
    DestViewController.viewTwo.text = "5"
}
}

}
```

At the bottom line of code, I get a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTUCTION (code:EXC_I386_INVOP, subside 0x0

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I get this error, but I think I already set up an if else statement to decide if the value is nil or not?

I put 0 and 5 in just to see if the code would function correctly and not have any errors...

Anyone have any help? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do test to see whether `UsernameForRegistrationText` is nil.

But you do *not* test to see whether `UsernameForRegistrationText.text` is nil. Therefore, if it is nil, you crash when you say `UsernameForRegistrationText.text!`

Remember, in Swift, any time you put an exclamation mark (`!`) after a reference, you are *asking* to crash.